# Best way to detect key presses without SDL or GLUT?

Tags: c++, input, keyboard

I've recently created a small application using OpenGL and GLUT via C++.
Everything was working great, and then I implemented a proper game loop with framerate and the like, and this made a lot of things better, however it also seemed to break the regular GLUT keyboard detection (which never seemed great for game keyboard input anyway) - so now I'm looking for another method of keyboard input in my application.

Could anyone suggest any other (preferably relatively easy) methods of detecting key inputs in an application?

Comment: If you're using the built-in OS API, we'll need to know what OS you're using (Windows, I assume?) Otherwise you could try another lightweight library like GLFW.

Comment: Not that I like GLUT, but why do you say glut keyboard input is bad? There are two modes of keyboard input with GLUT. One is like in text editors, when if you keep pressing a key, you will keep receiving it periodically. Another method (which is used with games) is to notify you when a key is pressed (so you change the state of the game) and when it is released (so you change the state back). The second method works perfect with games. By the way, the second method also works with SDL. I have written many games with it and they all work great.

Comment: @Shahbaz, sorry for mentioning the old comment and post, but freeglut even have several bugs that were not resolved for years like when pressing ctrl + number does not even fire the Keyborad callback, no Special Keyboard callback. You cannot distinguish between ctrl-break and ctrl -c because they are reported as the same ascii character ... The Keyboard handling in glut **is** bad. There are other bugs as well and thats only on Windows... https://sourceforge.net/p/freeglut/bugs/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> so now I'm looking for a decent method of keyboard input in my application.

No, you're looking at not using GLUT anymore.

On Windows at least, your ability to get input is directly tied to your window. If you don't have a window of some kind, you don't have input (the console is itself a window). And more importantly, if GLUT owns your window, then GLUT decides how the input from that window gets handled.

Therefore, if you're using GLUT, you have to use GLUT's input system. And if GLUT's input system isn't good enough for your needs, then it's time to ditch GLUT for greener pastures. After all, GLUT is intended for demos, not serious applications.

So you need a replacement for all the stuff GLUT does for you. You might be able to get away with [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/), but that might not be sufficient for your game. As such, [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/), [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/), and [Allegro 5](http://alleg.sourceforge.net/) are all possibilities. They have ways of spawning windows that use OpenGL, and they are all cross-platform. All of them has more effective and flexible input systems than GLUT.

Comment: I think I'll be switching from GLUT to SDL then *hopes that it'll be as simply as changing a few lines after including SDL.h*

Answer (score 2):

There isn't easy way. You need to track windows messages if you want input from OS and that's not going to happen if you use GLUT because it creates the window for you. Also another bad thing about GLUT is that it doesn't really track pressed keys, but characters entered, so pressing num1 and num1+shift generates 2 different things and for every keyboard layout these will be different. If you want to do proper keyboard handling, use either SDL or better SFML (google for it - simple and fast multimedia library). These allows you to track keypresses. Or if you don't want to use any library for that, you need to create and handle window for yourself and it won't be portable unless you make that code for every platform. Even if you don't want portable, programming with win32 is pain in the ass and you surely don't want to do that.

GLUT is simply not made for games, there's nothing more to it, and my advice is to use SFML.

**Update:**
In case you really want to mess with win32 (OS Windows case), assuming that you know how to create and handle your window, the message Windows sends to window is WM_KEYDOWN and pressed key identifier is stored as wParam. Here you can find all possible values [virtual keycodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms927178.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

There's [OIS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wgois/).  The Ogre people have some [documentation](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/OIS).